# MOSFET output I on Arduino

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I am trying to power a pair of TEC (thermo-electric cooler) using Arduino.  I came across [this guide](http://garagelab.com/profiles/blogs/how-to-use-a-peltier-with-arduino) that is used to power one.

Because I have two, I want to know if I can still use something such as [this mosfet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/RFP30N06LE.pdf/) (we want to supply ~12 A).  It says a drain current of 30 A, so I think that I could, but I have never worked with this high of current or power, and do not want to fry something or destroy the board.

Comment: You might want to add a 100 ohm resistor between the MOSFET gate and the arduino pin, otherwise you might stress the arduino port with rapid switching.

Comment: Datasheet link in question is broken. Link is https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/RFP30N06LE.pdf instead.

Answer (score 1):

Peltiers can be hard to figure out how much current they will draw because it is dependent on the temperature across the module. You could hook it directly up to the a power supply running at the same voltage as the supply rail to your mosfet, then check the current while your swinging the peltier module across the maximum temperatures that it will experience in operation. Then take the max current figure and make sure that is lower than the rated current of your mosfet. If your worried about the current then start with a lower supply current then ramp it up later when your confident the circuit is working. I would not parallel the peliters, but put them in series as you probably don't have matched modules and the mismatch could send much more current through the other module.